# Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is continuously differentiable ($f\in C^1$). Lets assume $\int_0^\infty f < \infty$ and $f'(x)$ is bounded. Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$.

All I could think of is doing integration by parts:

$$ \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n-1}^n 1\cdot f(x)\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \left.xf(x)\vphantom{\frac11}\right|_{n-1}^n - \int_{n-1}^n xf'(x) \, dx  \right)$$

Comment: The integrals should be from $n-1$ to $n$.

Comment: Oh right. I sensed something is wrong.

Comment: You have to evaluate $xf(x)$ at $n$ and $n-1$ inside the summation sign - thats how you do integration by parts.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that myself. Thank you!

Comment: And the penultimate majoration is false...

Comment: @RobertGreen, can you explain?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( xf(x) - \int_0^n xf'(x) dx\right) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( xf(x) - \int_0^n xM \right)$ --> why is $- \int_0^n xf'(x) dx \leq - \int_0^n xM dx$ ? I would say only $- \int_0^n xf'(x) dx \leq \int_0^n xM dx$

Comment: Maybe not the best way to go about it, but your hypotheses imply $f$ is uniformly continuous. You can argue as in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/f-uniformly-continuous-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-converges-imply-lim-x/92108).

Comment: $f$ is uniformly continuous and integrable, this implies it tends to $0$

Comment: I'll have a look at the related post, thank you in the meantime.

Comment: @DavidMitra, I've looked at the accepted answer there. I don't understand why is $f(q)$ must be $>\varepsilon/2$.

Comment: Use the result from this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/f-uniformly-continuous-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-converges-imply-lim-x?lq=1) and you can get the proof immediately.

Comment: @xpaul, Can you answer my question above regarding this post?

Comment: Writing $\int_0^\infty f < \infty$ is not useful unless f is nonnegative

Comment: Let $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$ and then use the following question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/396707/72031

Answer (score 0):

Define $F(x) = \int^x_0 f(t)dt$ and suppose $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F'(x) \neq 0$. This means there is $\epsilon > 0$ and an increasing sequence $\{x_n\}$ s.t. $x_n\rightarrow \infty$ and $|F'(x_n)| \geq \epsilon$ for all $n$.

Since $f(x) \in C^1$, $F'(x)$ is uniformly continuous. Thus there is $\delta>0$ s.t. for all $n$, if $|x - y| < \delta$, then $|F'(x) - F'(y)| < \epsilon/2$.
Note that this means for $x \in [x_n, x_n+\delta]$, by the triangle inequality,  $|f'(x)| \geq |f'(x_n)| - |f'(x) - f'(x_n)| > \epsilon/2$.

The assumption $\int^\infty_0 f(t)dt < \infty$ means $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |F(x_n + \delta) - F(x_n)| = 0$. However, $|F(x_n + \delta) - F(x_n)| \geq \left|\int^{x_n+\delta}_{x_n} F'(t)dt\right| \geq \int^{x_n+\delta}_{x_n} (\epsilon/2) dt = \epsilon \delta /2 > 0 $. Hence the contradiction.

Therefore, $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F'(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$.